# When pager loads for the first time view in first childViewController leaves space from both side for the first time

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xlpagertabstrip

when XLPagerTabStrip loads view in the first child view controller leave space from both sides but if I switched tabs then it acquires the screen as I wanted.

here is the screenshot of a simulator for understanding:

[image]

And after switching tabs it shows full-width view[As expected]:

[image]

my whole setup is normal tableview has nothing done in that its just a view and
here is XKPager setup

```
    settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = appBlueColor
    settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = appBlueColor

    settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = appBrownColor

    settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = UIFont.appRegularFontWith(size: 16)

    settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 4.0
    settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0

    settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
    settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailableWidth = true

    settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0

    changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
        guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
        oldCell?.label.textColor = self?.oldCellColor
        oldCell?.label.font = UIFont.appRegularFontWith(size: 16)

        newCell?.label.textColor = .white
        newCell?.label.font = UIFont.appMediumFontWith(size: 16)
    }

   override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "childViewController1")

    let child2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "childViewController1")

    let child3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "childViewController1")

    return [child1, child2, child3]
}
```

Xcode version: 11.2.1
swift version: 5
ios deployment target: 10.0
XLPager updated